# Data updating in the (phpMyAdmin) when I hit the Update CRUD in Angular 16 project but rest of the formfiels are empty

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to update entries in my database. The filed that i am editing is the only field that is getting updated, while rest of the fields are going blank in my DB(i.e previous values are getting overwritten) . I am using Angular 16 for frontend, NodeJs and typeORM for backend. Here is what i tried -->

```
// Update Staff Data Client Request in Staff Service -->  
    updateStaffDataByID(id : string, staff: Staff) :Observable<any>{
        return this.http.put(this.updateStaffURL+`/${id}`, staff)
        .pipe(
            catchError(ErrorHandler.errorHandle)
        )  
    }
```

```
// Forntend Code -->

 ngOnInit() {

    // for pre-filled data after clicking edit staff icon
    this.staffForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [""],
      middleName: [""],
      lastName: [""],
      department: [""],
      designation: [""],
      // dob: [""],
      // photo : [""],
      aadhar: [""],
      // isActive: [""]
    })

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(this.id)

    if (this.id != null) {
      this.getSingleStaff(this.id, () => {})
    } else {
      console.log("id is null")
    }

  }

  //Get Single Staff defined here -->
  getSingleStaff(id: string, calback: () => void) {
    console.log("Get single staff working fine!")
    this.staffService.getSingleStaffData(id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.dataSource = data.data
    })
  }

  // Update Staff defined here -->
  updateStaff() {
    console.log(this.id)
    const id = this.id ?? ""
    if (id.length > 0) {
      console.log("Update staff working fine! " + `${id}`)
      this.dataSource = this.staffForm.value
      this.staffService.updateStaffDataByID(id, this.dataSource).subscribe(async data => {
        console.log("****************************************")
        this.dataSource = data.data
        alert("Staff updated successfully!")
        console.log("id after updating the data = ",id)
        this.getSingleStaff(id, () => {})
        console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
        // this.router.navigate([`admin/home/detail-staff`+`/${id}`])
      })
    } else {
      console.log("Exiting: id is not available...")
    }
  }
```

```
// Backend Code -->
 //update Staff
  static async updateStaff(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const id: any = req.params.id
    const staffInDatabase = await staffRepository.findOneBy({ id: id })
    if (staffInDatabase == null) {
      res.status(500).json("data not found. enter valid id")
    }
    else {
      staffRepository.update(req.params.id, req.body)
      const id: any = req.params.id
      const updatedStaffInDatabase = await staffRepository.findOneBy({ id: id })
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "data updated ",
        data: updatedStaffInDatabase
        //incomplete chanfe req.body to variable to avoid sql injectioon
      })
    }

  }
```